# INSERT trigger causing trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert, dml

I'm new to writing SQL Server triggers. I have a table called `USERS` and I also a another tabled called `USERS_DELTA`. The difference between the two is `USERS_DELTA` has one additional column called `change_type`.

Here are the table schema:

`USERS` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TDR_Users]
(
    [objectGUID] [varbinary](50) NOT NULL,
    [distinguishedName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [adForest] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [adDomain] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [accountExpires] [datetime] NULL,
    [adminCount] [int] NULL,
    [cn] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [company] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](448) NULL,
    [displayName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [division] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [employeeID] [nvarchar](16) NULL
)
```

And `USERS_DELTA` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TDR_Users]
(
    [objectGUID] [varbinary](50) NOT NULL,
    [distinguishedName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [adForest] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [adDomain] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [accountExpires] [datetime] NULL,
    [adminCount] [int] NULL,
    [cn] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [company] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](448) NULL,
    [displayName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [division] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [employeeID] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    [change_Type] [nvarchar](10) NULL
)
```

I have an application which will be creating records in `USERS` table. But what I'm trying to do is capture the inserts into the `USERS_DELTA`. I have written a trigger on the `USERS` table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_INSERTS_DELTAS]
   ON  [dbo].[Users]
   FOR INSERT
AS 
    DECLARE @ObjectGUID varbinary(50), @DN varchar(255), @memcount int;
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Get the primary and unique keys from the inserted rows.
    SELECT @DN=i.distinguishedName  FROM inserted i;
    SELECT @ObjectGUID = i.objectGUID FROM inserted i;  

    -- Check if a row already exists in the TDR_Users_Delta table with those values.
    SELECT @memcount=COUNT(*) FROM Users 
    WHERE Users.distinguishedName = @DN 
    AND Users.objectGUID = @ObjectGUID ;
    if(@memcount = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users_Delta]
        (
            [objectGUID],
            [distinguishedName],
            [adForest],
            [adDomain],
            [accountExpires],
            [adminCount],
            [cn] ,
            [company],
            [description],
            [displayName],
            [division],
            [employeeID],
            [change_type]
        )

        VALUES
        (
            INSERTED.[objectGUID],
            INSERTED.[distinguishedName],
            INSERTED.[adForest],
            INSERTED.[adDomain],
            INSERTED.[accountExpires],
            INSERTED.[adminCount],
            INSERTED.[cn] ,
            INSERTED.[company],
            INSERTED.[description],
            INSERTED.[displayName],
            INSERTED.[division],
            INSERTED.[employeeID],
            'Add'           
        );

    END
END
GO
```

When I execute this trigger, I get the following error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TR_INSERTS_DELTAS, Line 94
>   The multi-part identifier "Inserted.objectGUID" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TR_INSERTS_DELTAS, Line 95
>   The multi-part identifier "INSERTED.distinguishedName" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TR_INSERTS_DELTAS, Line 96
>   The multi-part identifier "INSERTED.adForest" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TR_INSERTS_DELTAS, Line 97
>   The multi-part identifier "INSERTED.adDomain" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TR_INSERTS_DELTAS, Line 98
>   ...

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: Please ignore the name in the table schema. I know it says TDR_USERS. I have already corrected it on my end but the error still persists. Think its something in the code of the trigger.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @DN=i.distinguishedName  FROM inserted i;` - it's non-deterministic - you'll get one row and ignore all 24 others! You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: To take marc_s comment another way.  Think of a History table not a delta table.  So always insert a row on every change.   This means the history table will need  a different primary key such as employee id and date of change GetDate().  You would never need to know the primary key beforehand in a history table concept.    All of my best and longest lasting highest volume most stable database projects have zero triggers in them

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to put a select with the table in rather than using inserted.x to signify the insert.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_INSERTS_DELTAS]
   ON  [dbo].[Users]
   FOR INSERT
AS 
DECLARE @ObjectGUID varbinary(50), @DN varchar(255), @memcount int;
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Get the primary and unique keys from the inserted rows.
    SELECT @DN=i.distinguishedName  FROM inserted i;
    SELECT @ObjectGUID = i.objectGUID FROM inserted i;  

    -- Check if a row already exists in the TDR_Users_Delta table with those values.
    SELECT @memcount=COUNT(*) FROM Users 
    WHERE Users.distinguishedName = @DN 
    AND Users.objectGUID = @ObjectGUID ;
    if(@memcount = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users_Delta]
        (
            [objectGUID],
            [distinguishedName],
            [adForest],
            [adDomain],
            [accountExpires],
            [adminCount],
            [cn] ,
            [company],
            [description],
            [displayName],
            [division],
            [employeeID],
            [change_type]
        )

        select
            INSERTED.[objectGUID],
            INSERTED.[distinguishedName],
            INSERTED.[adForest],
            INSERTED.[adDomain],
            INSERTED.[accountExpires],
            INSERTED.[adminCount],
            INSERTED.[cn] ,
            INSERTED.[company],
            INSERTED.[description],
            INSERTED.[displayName],
            INSERTED.[division],
            INSERTED.[employeeID],
            'Add'
From inserted
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: You should remove those two lines: `SELECT @DN=i.distinguishedName  FROM inserted i; SELECT @ObjectGUID = i.objectGUID FROM inserted i;` since they really don't do anything, and they'll **fail** if `inserted` has more than one row ....